# Querying a user's group membership from Active Directory

Tags: c#, active-directory, ldap

I wanted to know if there's a fast way to query information from Active Directory.

Specifically, I'm trying to query the current user's "member of" groups which starts with a given string, say "abc-" for example.

If any one can help me I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Welcome to SO, Matt! I have edited your question for clarity. If you don't like the changes I made or wish to further edit your question, please use the "edit" link to make the changes you desire.

Answer (score 2):

[Linq to ActiveDirectory](http://linqtoad.codeplex.com/) is an option that you can consider.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in different ways, [Managing Directory Security Principals in the .NET Framework 3.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc135979.aspx#S8)
helps you this way:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
  /* Retreiving a principal context
   */
  PrincipalContext domainContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "WM2008R2ENT", "dc=dom,dc=fr", "TheUser", "ThePassword");

  /* Discribe the group You are looking for as a principal
   */
  GroupPrincipal gpPrincipal = new GroupPrincipal(domainContext);
  gpPrincipal.Name = "abc-*";

  /* Bind a searcher
   */
  PrincipalSearcher searcher = new PrincipalSearcher();
  searcher.QueryFilter = gpPrincipal;

  PrincipalSearchResult<Principal> hRes = searcher.FindAll();

  /* Read The result
   */
  foreach (GroupPrincipal grp in hRes)
  {
    Console.WriteLine(grp.Name);
    // You are looking for "grp.Members"
  }

  Console.ReadLine();
}
```

I hope it helps.