# Recursively search Active Directory for groups only

Tags: c#, active-directory

Currently I am working on  project that involves Active Directory programming via C#. This project requires :

1. retrieve a list groups (till sentinel) within a group.
2. Save this list in SQL Server DB.

Synchronize the retrieval process so that from second time only delta is received.

Comment: `Synchronize the retrieval process so that from second time only delta is received.` This is impossible. You can retrieve all the data, calculate the delta yourself and only update the database with changes, but you will never get AD to do the work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Implement your own code and try to achieve functionality. Refer below link for api code.

[get all users from a group in Active Directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7915145/get-all-users-from-a-group-in-active-directory)

Comment: All the solutions implemented in the post mentioned by you use tries to retrieve a list of user.I need list of groups only.